# all linux installation stops at error ""intramfs unable to..." version 14

Tags: boot, xubuntu, lubuntu

installation stops at ""initramfs unable find a medium containing live file system "" i have tried lubuntu , xubuntu ,ubuntu all are giving me errors ..iam using bootable usb and using Universal-USB-Installer-1.9.5.6(1).exe as instructed on pendrive linux

quick specs p4 3.ghz 512mb ram ,32bit
hdd is pata 80gb
i researched and found that it is bios setting problem....

ubuntu version is ubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso
xubuntu version is xubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386_2.iso
lubuntu version is lubuntu-14.04.1-desktop-i386.iso

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try not using universal usb installer.

The ubuntu installer iso can made bootable on usb simply by using `dd` eg:

`dd if=/home/user/Download/ubuntu-1404.iso of=/dev/sdb # where /dev/sdb is the device file of you USB stick`

Of course you need a system to do this on that has `dd`, Linux,OSX other unix's generally have `dd` by default, however you can use [cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/) on windows and this comes with `dd`.